# What will be the sum of some 3 consecutive numbers must be at least?

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

Let 1 to 20 are placed in any around a circle. Then the sum of some 3 consecutive numbers must be at least

(a) 30

(b) 31

(c) 32

(d) none

---

**My approach**

**each number participates in exactly three triplets. Since the numbers add up to  210,
the triplets add up to  630 There are 20 of them, so the average triplet has sum  31.5. but it has to be an integer so the ans should be 32**

*But my doubt is  {1,2,3} be also a triplet.At that time it will violate my solution.*

Comment: We want to show that the sum of *some* $3$ consecutive numbers must be at least $32$, not any set of three consecutive numbers.

Comment: @fleablood:  we are taking the maximum sum of three consecutive in a given arrangement, then taking the minimum of that over all arrangements.  In any arrangement there will be at least one triplet with a sum of at least $32$.

Comment: Okay, I didn't get that the numbers weren't in order.

Comment: I'd quibble that if one of them is at least $32$ than it is also at least $30$ or $31$.  For the question to make sense they should have some options that *don't* need to be reached.

Comment: This argument merely proves that the answer must be *at least* $32$.  It doesn't prove that there's some arrangement for which the answer is, in fact, $32$.

Comment: " It doesn't prove that there's some arrangement for which the answer is, in fact, 32"  I don't think anyone is claim there is.

Comment: Then the question is very badly phrased, because if $32$ isn't actually realized, then $30$ and $31$ are answers that are just as good as $32$.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is correct, if a little poorly worded.  Each triplet must have a sum that is an integer, and if a set of integers have an average of $31.5$ some of them have to be at least $32$.  As N. F. Taussig says, we are looking for the maximum sum of three consecutive numbers, then taking the minimum of that over all arrangements.  However if $32$ is correct, so are $30$ and $31$ because whatever number is at least $32$ is also at least $31$.

Comment: Seems to me that this merely proves that $32$ is a lower bound for the minimum over all arrangements.  It's not a proof that the lower bound is actually realized.

Comment: @RobertShore:  that is correct.  I can imagine that the minimum would be a little higher.